# Android KeyStore Access

Tags: java, android, keystore

I´m new at developing Android Apps.
However I want to generate a RSA Keypair for later encryption/decryption.

I heard about the Android Keystore to store such Keys and get them from there.

My Question: Is there a "default" KeyStore on the Android Device or do I have to create one?

How would that work? I´ve seen tutorials about Keystores, but only for signing APK´s.

René

Comment: when go to the "Build" tab at the main menu at the top of the screen, select "Generate Signed APK" and it will give u the choice to use or create a keystore, this keystore is gonna be used to sign your app to use certain features like firebase auth and so on, and to upload the app on the playstore, once u upload an app to the store, that keystore is always gonna be the final one, u get 1 change per lifetime, so don't lose it or lose the alias/passwords for it

Comment: Is my new created keystore automatically in my app?Let's say we have have a new keystore named xx.keystore and I have my Keystore.load method, how do I load my keystore xx.keystore?

Comment: And I dont want to publish my app in google play store.

Comment: it's created somewhere on your machine, and u have to write where you want to use it within the app, check the google docs

Comment: creating a keystore does not mean the app is uploaded to store, it's just 1 requirement to upload, u don't have to do it

Comment: When I have created the Keystore on my Computer, and I want to share my app with other persons do I have to load it on their device manually or can I just create a folder in my Project and place it there?

Comment: u can drop it anywhere in your project structure, at the end you will write the path to the keystore anyway

Comment: ok now i´ve created my keystore and can access them. When i want to create a RSA keypair with keypairgenerator class, i have to pass a provider / provider string to it.
From certain tutorials I´ve seen that they use the word "AndroidKey" as provider.
I think they access a preinstalled Keystore with that.
Question: What is this provider for and which value should I pass to it in my case having a custom keystore file?

Comment: sure it was AndroidKey and not androiddebugkey ?

Comment: sry it was "AndroidKeystore"